# Smartgit: Moving local changes from stash to branch

Tags: git, smartgit

I have local changes which I have stored in stash. I have now (afterwards) created a new branch and want to push my changes from stash to this branch. SmartGit: Local > Apply stash.

When I try to SmartGit asks me: Restore Index (checkbox), what is this? Should I select it or not?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The **Restore Index** option will result in a `git stash apply --index`. According to [the git man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html), this means:

> If the --index option is used, then tries to reinstate not only the
>   working tree’s changes, but also the index’s ones. However, this can
>   fail, when you have conflicts (which are stored in the index, where
>   you therefore can no longer apply the changes as they were
>   originally).

So, in general, yes, you should try to apply the stash having this option enabled.

Comment: Here is --index explained with an example, which makes things clearer:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: To quote the link @ThomasLauria provided: `The changes to your files were reapplied, but the file you staged before wasn’t restaged. To do that, you must run the git stash apply command with a --index option to tell the command to try to reapply the staged changes.`

Comment: And what is the "Apply & Drop" button for?